# Is there a method in JavaScript to get End date based on Start date and Number of days?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $('#n_days').change(function(){
    var nstart_date = $("#start_date").val();
    alert (nstart_date);

    var ndays = document.getElementById('n_days').value;
    alert (ndays);
    
    var end_date1 = new Date(nstart_date); // pass start date here
    alert (end_date1);
    
    enddate.setDate(end_date.getDate() + n_days);
    
    var end= $('#end_date').val( (end_date.getMonth() + 1)+ '/' + end_date.getDate() + '/' + end_date.getFullYear() );
    $("#end_date").val(dat);
  });
});
```

```html
   

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

How to get 'end date' filled out based on start date and number of days. I want the user to enter 'start date' and when they enter 'number of days' then automatically end date should be filled out. For example: If user enters start date- 03/10/2020 and number of days-5 then end date should be 08/10/2020.

Comment: @Andreas, Hope I have simplified the code. If not please advise some tips to correct it. I am a new user. Thanks.

Comment: Your markup is invalid (`</tr><td>`, `</p>` without `<p>`, `<font><font>...`, ...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0):

I added a `prototype` function to `date object` so that we can call add days to start date and second thing i did is that date control expects value in `YYYY-MM-dd` format which you get by calling `toISOString()` on date object. below code snipped should solve your problem.

reference post used for adding prototype function to date object. you may spend some time on this post to learn more.
[Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  debugger;
  var date = new Date(this);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + Number(days));
  return date;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#n_days').change(function() {
    var nstart_date = $("#start_date").val();
    alert(nstart_date);

    var ndays = document.getElementById('n_days').value;
    alert(ndays);

    var end_date1 = new Date(nstart_date).addDays(ndays);
    alert(end_date1)
    var endDateFormatted = end_date1.toISOString().substr(0, 10)
    document.getElementById('end_date').value = endDateFormatted;

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form id="form1" name="form1" action="add_con.php" method="post">
    <table id="t01">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-40">
              <label for="startdate">start date:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-60">
              <input type="date" id="start_date" name="start_date" size="20">
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <td>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-40">
            <label for="n_daysa">No. of days:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-60">
            <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 12pt">
              <font size="4">
                <input type="number" id="n_days" name="n_days" min=0 placeholder="Enter no. of days.." required size="20" style="font-size:14px"></font>
            </font>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-40">
            <label for="end_datea">&nbsp;end date:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-60">
            <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 12pt">
              <input type="date" id="end_date" name="end_date" placeholder="End date.." required size="20" style="font-size:14px">
            </font>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </p>
    <div class="row">
      <p align="center">
        <font face="Cambria">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </font>
        <font face="Cambria">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset">
        </font>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: One more thing to ask, how can we enable other date fields based on the Input from 'Number of days'. I have another 9 date fields (date2--date10) and I want to  auto-fill the date as per the entry in 'Number of days'. For example: If user inputs start date- 03/10/2020 and number of days- 5 and end-date - 08/10/2020
then it should display like:

date2- 04/10/2020,
date3- 05/10/2020,
date4- 06/10/2020,
date5- 07/10/2020,
date6- 08/10/2020,
date7- disabled,
date8- disabled,
date9- disabled,
date10- disabled

added the new date fields in the code. Thanks.

Comment: rather than updating the OP can you accept this as answer and ask another question including the `html`+`js` of what you want to achieve and people will be happy to help. your original question has been already answered so its better that we should move to next question in a new thread and close this by accepting and upvoting if this helped.

Comment: Sure, I will ask in other question.

Comment: I have opened another thread to ask this question. Sandeep please see if you can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please accept/upvote my answer first so that this question can considered complete.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the answer for your question below. You can also pass negative values to the function addDays() to get previous dates.

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function (num) {
    var value = this.valueOf();
    value += 86400000 * num;
    return new Date(value);
}
$('#n_days').change(function(){
    var $datepicker = $('#start_date');
    var $datepicker1 = $('#end_date');
    
    var selectedDate = $datepicker.val();
    var result = new Date(selectedDate);
    var dateval = result.getDate();
    
    var ndays = $('#n_days').val();
    numdays =  Number(ndays);
    
    var expirationDate = result.addDays(numdays);
    
     end_date1 = new Date(expirationDate);
     var day = ("0" + end_date1.getDate()).slice(-2);
     var month = ("0" + (end_date1.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
     var year = end_date1.getFullYear();
     var newdate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
     $datepicker1.val(newdate);

});


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
 <script src= 
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" > 
    </script> 

<div class="container">
 
 <form id="form1" name="form1" action="add_con.php" method="post">
      
 <table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <td>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-40">
        <label for="startdate">start date:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-60">
     
        <input type="date" id="start_date" name="start_date" size="20" >
      </div>
    </div>
    </td>
  
  </tr>
 
 
  <td> <div class="row">
      <div class="col-40">
        <label for="n_daysa">No. of days:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-60">
          <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 12pt">
          <font size="4">
         <input type="number" id="n_days" name="n_days" min=0 placeholder="Enter no. of days.." required size="20" style="font-size:14px"></font>
       </font>
      </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-40">
        <label for="end_datea">&nbsp;end date:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-60">
           <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 12pt">
          <input type="date" id="end_date" name="end_date" placeholder="End date.." required size="20" style="font-size:14px">
          </font>

      </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>

</table>
 <br><br><br>
 <hr color="#003399">

  
<!-- start second table-->

<table class="table1" style="width:1209;" height="151">
  <tr>
    <th height="21" width="34"><font color="#003399">Day</font></th>
    <th height="21" width="295"><font color="#003399">Date</font></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="1" width="34"><b>2</b></td>
<td width="200" height="1">
    <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 11pt">
    <input type="date" id="date2" name="date2" size="10" style="width: 90%; "></font></td>
    </tr>
  
<tr>
<td height="1" width="34"><b>3</b></td>
<td width="200" height="1">
    <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 11pt">
    <input type="date" id="date3" name="date3" size="10" style="width: 90%;"></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="1" width="34"><b>4</b></td>
<td width="200" height="1">
    <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 11pt">
    <input type="date" id="date4" name="date4" size="10" style="width: 90%;"></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="1" width="34"><b>5</b></td>
<td width="200" height="1">
    <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 11pt">
    <input type="date" id="date5" name="date5" size="10" style="width: 90%;"></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="1" width="34"><b>6</b></td>
<td width="200" height="1">
    <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 11pt">
    <input type="date" id="date6" name="date6" size="10" style="width: 90%;"></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="1" width="34"><b>7</b></td>
<td width="200" height="1">
    <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 11pt">
    <input type="date" id="date7" name="date7" size="10" style="width: 90%;"></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="1" width="34"><b>8</b></td>
<td width="200" height="1">
    <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 11pt">
    <input type="date" id="date8" name="date8" size="10" style="width: 90%;"></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="1" width="34"><b>9</b></td>
<td width="200" height="1">
    <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 11pt">
    <input type="date" id="date9" name="date9" size="10" style="width: 90%;"></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="1" width="34"><b>10</b></td>
<td width="200" height="1">
    <font face="Cambria" style="font-size: 11pt">
    <input type="date" id="date10" name="date10" size="10" style="width: 90%;"></font></td>
</tr>
</table>


<!-- end second table -->

    <div class="row">
      <p align="center">
      <font face="Cambria">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"></font>

      <font face="Cambria">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset"> </font>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is working fine.

One more thing to ask, how can we enable other date fields based on the Input from 'Number of days'. I have another 9 date fields (date2--date10) and I want to  auto-fill the date as per the entry in 'Number of days'. For example: If user inputs start date- 03/10/2020 and number of days- 5 and end-date - 08/10/2020
then it should display like:

date2- 04/10/2020,
date3- 05/10/2020,
date4- 06/10/2020,
date5- 07/10/2020,
date6- 08/10/2020,
date7- disabled,
date8- disabled,
date9- disabled,
date10- disabled

added the new date fields in your code. Please suggest..Thanks.

Comment: Please open a new thread for this question so that it can be helpful to someone else also.